# Remove numbers in front of file[working] + append number to duplicate filenames[not-working]

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript which removes any numbers and/or hyphens and underscores from the beginning of a filename. That works fine.
However, sometimes I might have a situation like this:

```
 Filename Eg;  01-Dog.jpg,  02-Dog.jpg,  03-Dog.jpg, etc.
```

In such a case, the script stops/does not run, only telling me that there already is a file with that name. It does not tell me which file its conflicting with (sometimes there are A LOT of files to look through).

Could somebody please help in modifying this script so that in such a case, a file with the same name would have a number OR letter appended to the end of a filename (before the extension).

**Eg; Dog2.jpg, Dog3.jpg, etc.**

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with thisFile in input
        tell application "Finder"
            set filename to name of (thisFile as alias)
            set filename to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of filename & " | sed 's/^[0-9_-]*//'")
            set name of thisFile to filename
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "a file with the same name would have a number OR letter appended to the end of a filename (before the extension)". Do you mean it would be like 01-Dog and 01-Dog2, or would it be like 01-Dog and 01-DogA

Comment: It already is: 01-Dog and 01-Dog2. The first Eg shows this.
The second Eg is what i wish for the file to look like.
Dog2.jpg, Dog3.jpg OR Dog-A.jpg, Dog-B.jpg etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to do the renaming inside a try block, so that if it errors, you can add the 1, 2, 3... to the name and then attempt again.
Here's a version that will work:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with thisFile in input
        tell application "Finder" to set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension} of (thisFile as alias)
        set theName to text 1 thru ((offset of ("." & theExtension) in theName) - 1) of theName
        set theName to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theName & " | sed 's/^[0-9_-]*//'")
        set n to ""
        repeat 30 times -- will work for up to 30 versions of the same file name
            try
                tell application "Finder" to set name of thisFile to (theName & n & "." & theExtension)
                exit repeat
            on error errMsg
                if errMsg contains "already an item with that name" then
                    if n is "" then
                    set n to 2
                    else
                    set n to (n as integer) + 1
                    end if
                else
                    display dialog errMsg
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end try
        end repeat
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

The offset line is to show how to get the base name of the file. You need to capture the base name separate from the extension in order to append the 1, 2, 3… Crazy that the Finder dictionary has the name extension property, but not a base name property. However, I'd then just write the truncating the extension into the sed call. If you will have files without an extension, will need to add an error check for that.

Comment: The principal works only slight problem. 
If there are 3 or more files(with same name), the third filename is appended with a "12" instead of "2". The 4th filename gets a "123" instead of just "3". etc.

Comment: I KNOW... when I woke up this morning, that flaw popped into my head. I have changed the code, so that the n variable gets added on the fly, instead of tacking it on each iteration of the repeat. Also, not that the "30 times" limit is self-imposed, to avoid never-ending scripts. If you'll have some that exceed that amount, change it to 500 or whatever.

Comment: Works fantastic! The only thing.....Is it possible for the increments to begin at 2 rather than 1?

Comment: Of course it's possible. I just added another little edit to make that change. Kindly accept the answer for future reference. Let me know if you need any other tweaks.